# How to separate json response in different variables?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs

How do I separate this response in one variable, like I required from below response URL only in one variable? However, "BE050-A28" this value is dynamic in every response.

```js
{
  "vehicle": {
    "BE050-A28": {
      "url": "https://europe.com/iris/iris.jpg?COSY-EU-100-1713d0VXqNSFqtyO35PobzIDneWql9TQw2Mpxikzmxxom7ssM0uBRBbB2Z0iD%25W%25NZWm7ymWdhK0h8f%25v8%257EyLibLlYa4IG2rH"
    }
  }
}

var responsePayload = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(Stringify(response));
var responseUrl = Stringify(responsePayload.vehicle.url);
Write("responseUrl : " + responseUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this after parsing the JSON into a JS object:

```
var myObj = {
               foo:
               {
                  foo1: //dynamic Key here
                  {
                     url:'https://bar.com'
                   }
               }
            };

var urlNeeded = myObj.foo[Object.keys(myObj.foo)[0]].url;
```

Comment: Hi Bryan, Thanks for response.

Comment: Actually I'm doing this code in SFMC under Content block.

Comment: Edited my answer to reflect

Comment: No Luck.. Bryan

Comment: Error: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Comment: In your original post, can you `console.log(responsePayload)` right after you perform the `ParseJSON` function

Comment: Thanks Bryan..issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Below class

```
public class SampleResponse {
     public class UrlInfo {
         String url;
     }
     Map<String, UrlInfo> vehicle; 
}

//sample input 
String s = '{"vehicle": {"BE050-A28": {  "url": "https://europe.com/iris/iris.jpg?COSY-EU-100-1713d0VXqNSFqtyO35PobzIDneWql9TQw2Mpxikzmxxom7ssM0uBRBbB2Z0iD%25W%25NZWm7ymWdhK0h8f%25v8%257EyLibLlYa4IG2rH"}}}';

//deserialize the response
SampleResponse res = (SampleResponse)JSON.deserialize(s, SampleResponse.class);
//Iterate through the keys 
if ( res.vehicle != null ) {
    for (String key : res.vehicle.keySet ()) {
        System.debug ('KEY : ' + key);   
        System.debug ('VALUE :' + res.vehicle.get (key));   
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Sudarshan

I tried with this code...but no luck..getting error.

Comment: Can you tell me what you have tried. I can demo you as well

Comment: var url = "";
  var clonedResponse = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(response.Content);
  Write("clonedResponse :"+clonedResponse);
    for(var vehicleKey in clonedResponse) {
      if(clonedResponse.hasOwnProperty(vehicleKey)) {
            var value = clonedResponse[vehicleKey];
            for(var imageKey in value) {
              var imageKeyValue = value[imageKey];
              var url = Stringify(imageKeyValue.url);

Comment: Write("url : "+url+'\n'); 
              Platform.Function.ContentBlockByKey("015f61d8-d3b7-48c0-bb09-e8b97c5a07e2");
              Variable.SetValue("@FURL", url);

Above work for me.. Sudarshan Thank you for Idea